# How to call a JSON Rest web service with Tomee 1.6

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, apache-tomee

My application is running on a *Tomee plus 1.6* JEE server.
I need to call a RS WS that will return an object formatted as a JSon string.

I can do that with an *openConnection("url")*, and a manual parsing of the response. But I think there is a much higher way to do that in a JEE environment.
The problem is that I found many tutorials about how to write a Restful WS, but very few about how to invoke them. Moreover, eachtime, there are several libraries to add to the Tomee server (Jackson, ...).

My questions are :

- is there any **standard** way to invoque a WS with no library to add ? I think there must be one because Tomee plus is supposed to be a full JEE server.
- how to do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you are using spring then you can use `RestTemplate`. if not then I would suggest looking at HttpClient and then use JSON parser to convert json to object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on tomee 7 but still tomee 1 you can use CXF WebClient to do that. TomEE 7 would let you use standard JAX-RS 2 client (part of EE 7) but was not in TomEE 1 (EE 6)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options to consume REST applications in Java nowadays. The current standard is the JAX-RS Client API, released in JAX-RS 2.0, and it's part of the Java EE 7 API.

***Important:** Once your are using Apache TomEE 1.6.0, which is Java EE 6 certified, the JAX-RS Client API won't be available for you. Keep reading.*

### JAX-RS Client API

The JAX-RS Client API ([`javax.ws.rs.client`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html) package), defined in the [JSR 339](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf) and released as part of the Java EE 7 API, is the standard way to consume REST web services in Java. Besides others, this specification is implemented by [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html), [RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.16.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html) and [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html).

### Vendor specific proxy frameworks

Both [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html), [RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.16.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html) and [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html) also provide a proxy framework API. Those APIs are vendor specific and are not part of the JAX-RS Client API.

The basic idea is you can attach the [standard JAX-RS annotations to an interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs002.htm#GINNA), and then implement that interface by a resource class on the server side while reusing the same interface on the client side by dynamically generating an implementation of that using [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) calling the right low-level client API methods.

For more details check the following:

- [Jersey proxy-based client API](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/proxy/package-summary.html)
- [RESTEasy proxy-based client API](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#d4e2149)
- [Apache CXF proxy-based client API](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-Proxy-basedAPI)

### Other resources

Here are some other options that you could consider as alternative to the JAX-RS Client API:

- [Apache CXF WebClient API](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-CXFWebClientAPI) <sup>†</sup>
- [Spring RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)
- [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)
- [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
- [Netflix Feign](https://github.com/Netflix/feign)

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> **[Apache CXF WebClient API](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-CXFWebClientAPI):** It's shipped with the Apache TomEE 1.6.0. In the `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs.jar` you are going to find the [`WebClient`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.html) class, which is the entry point to the client API.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help.

Finally, I decided to use the standard JAX-RS API, but as it was not released yet in Tomee 1.6, I had to add a jar file in the lib directory of the server :
javax.json-1.0.4.jar, which I downloaded from Oracle web site.

To compile my project, I had to use an other jar file : javax.json-api-1.0.4.jar

Answer (score -2):

Since you have mentioned that you are using TomEE plus 1.6, you already have JAX-RS client (Ref: [Apache TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)) which can be used to access REST WS.

The `javax.ws.rs.client` can be used to invoke the REST service and receive the response. More detailed tutorial can be found on [Oracle Site](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-client.htm).

EDIT: Missed the version number part. The API is available in 1.7.

Comment: It's incorrect! The JAX-RS Client API was released in JAX-RS 2.0 and it's part of the Java EE 7 API. Apache TomEE 1.6.0 is Java EE 6 certified. Hence, the JAX-RS Client API is not available in Apache TomEE 1.6.0. Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39389538/1426227) for more details.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin you are correct. I edited the answer.

Comment: It does not answer the question though.